# How to join my tables with ID's that do not match

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have these tables:

**payments**

```
| id | src_account | dest_account | payment_value |  
+----+-------------+--------------+---------------+
|  1 | xxxxxxxxxxx | yyyyyyyyyyyy |      200      |
```

**client_account**

```
| client_id | account_id  | 
+-----------+-------------+ 
|     3     | xxxxxxxxxxx |  
|     4     | yyyyyyyyyyy |
```

**client**

```
| id | firstname |  lastname  |
+----+-----------+------------+
|  3 |   Sofia   |  Lenhark   |
|  4 |   Mark    |  Davoreski |
```

Now I need to `select` the following fields in a SQL Query:

- Source Firstname
- Source Lastname
- Destination Firstname
- Destination Lastname
- Payment Value

I have tried the following:

```
SELECT
srcClientDetails.firstname,
srcClientDetails.lastname,
destClientDetails.firstname,
destClientDetails.lastname,
Payments.payment_value

FROM
dbo.payment AS Payments
LEFT JOIN dbo.client_account AS srcClientAccount ON Payments.src_account = srcClientAccount.account_id
LEFT JOIN dbo.client AS srcClientDetails ON srcClientAccount.client_id = srcClientDetails.id
LEFT JOIN dbo.client_account AS destClientAccount ON Payments.dest_account = destClientAccount.account_id
LEFT JOIN dbo.client AS destClientDetails ON destClientAccount.client_id = destClientDetails.id
```

But this is returning only the payment value, without any other data.

Why aren't the other desired fields being returned?

Comment: client to client account inner join.. then left join to payments then group by and sum

Comment: if you only want to get info for the payment then just use inner join on all tables.

Comment: which would you like to sum up is from src or destination?

Comment: First figure out which RDBMS you're using

Comment: @maSTAShuFu I don't want to SUM it, I need only to replace account number by names of owners. 
Strawberry Sorry, I'm using SQL-Server

Comment: the query seems correct .. have you tried  using an alias for your column names?

Comment: don't tag MySQL and SQL Server at the same time, these are different RDBMS

Comment: @scaisEdge Yes but still same nothing.

Comment: are you sure that the data involved  really match ????

Comment: The destination account id values were not the same. See answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Suggestions

### (1) Try it in INNER JOIN

To check that the `JOIN` is correct (Values are equal),first test the query using `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.payment AS Payments
INNER JOIN dbo.client_account AS srcClientAccount ON Payments.src_account = 
srcClientAccount.account_id
```

and check if it returns values or not, then add another table:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.payment AS Payments
INNER JOIN dbo.client_account AS srcClientAccount ON Payments.src_account = 
srcClientAccount.account_id
INNER JOIN dbo.client AS srcClientDetails ON srcClientAccount.client_id = srcClientDetails.id
```

And so on... This may leads you to the issue

### (2) Account id difference due to collation or additional spaces

I think this will lead you to the problem, it may be caused due to a case sensitive collation or length sensitive or additional spaces. To diagnose this issue, you can also try converting both columns to same case and length and Trim additional spaces.

```
ON LTRIM(RTRIM(UPPER(CAST(Payments.src_account as varchar(50))))) = LTRIM(RTRIM(UPPER(CAST(srcClientAccount.account_id as varchar(50)))))
```

If this fixes the problem than **it is better to edit the data (adding relations or constraints) rather than using this functions in the `Join` because it decrease the performance and doesn't use indexes.**

### (3) Create relations between tables

From the question it seems that there is no relation between columns, create the relations so values are constrained.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic was right, just the `[client_account].account_id` was 1 `'y'` short for matching, or `Payments.dest_account` needs 1 less `'y'`.

For example, you can see here I added 1 `'y'` to the `[client_account].account_id` and your query now returns the correct information:

```
WITH Payments AS (
    SELECT '1' as id,
    'xxxxxxxxxxx' as src_account,
    'yyyyyyyyyyyy' as dest_account,
    '200' as payment_value),
client_account AS (
    SELECT '3' as client_id,
    'xxxxxxxxxxx' as account_id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '4' as client_id,
    'yyyyyyyyyyyy' as 'account_id'),  --added a 'y' here
client AS (
    SELECT '3' as id,
    'Sofia' as firstname,
    'Lenhark' as lastname
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '4' as id,
    'Mark' as firstname,
    'Davoreski' as lastname)


SELECT
srcClientDetails.firstname,
srcClientDetails.lastname,
destClientDetails.firstname,
destClientDetails.lastname,
Payments.payment_value
FROM
payments AS Payments
LEFT JOIN client_account AS srcClientAccount ON Payments.src_account = srcClientAccount.account_id
LEFT JOIN client AS srcClientDetails ON srcClientAccount.client_id = srcClientDetails.id
LEFT JOIN client_account AS destClientAccount ON Payments.dest_account = destClientAccount.account_id
LEFT JOIN client AS destClientDetails ON destClientAccount.client_id = destClientDetails.id
```

[image]

[Try it here](http://rextester.com/CBDY23342)

Comment: Just a note, you can change your `LEFT JOIN` to `INNER JOIN` in all cases here and the results will still be valid.